# 2/4 time signature, miscounting?

Tags: piano, time-signatures, chopin, tuplet

I'm trying to to practice my 2/4 time signature. Am I just making a stupid mistake with the attached image? They are 1/16th notes? so shouldn't there only be 8 of them to make up two beats and not 12? I am pretty out of practice, so am sure it is just me!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the four groups of 3 sixteenth notes has a "3" under them. This indicates that each group of 3 notes is a "[triplet](https://www.mymusictheory.com/for-students/grade-2/208-15-triplets)" and so is played in the same time as 2 such notes. That makes the arithmetic add up.

Comment: @Mathlearner traditionally, the three notes to which the *3* applies would be under a curved line.  More recently, the triplet-grouping-line might be a square bracket so as to avoid the confusion with a slur or other articulation mark.  Here, the engraver relies on the beaming for this purpose, which makes the *3* harder to notice (and, in some contexts, could create ambiguity with fingering marks).  In some older scores, the *3* might be absent entirely, the performer being left to infer the triplet from the fact that there are 50% more of them than there normally ought to be.